# Java - scanning lines into a constructor

Tags: java, constructor, java.util.scanner

I've been stuck on this homework for a while. Basically I have to create a constructor for dates that reads a file, which consists of one date on each line. Each date should be stored in a Date object.

However, I have to print out the date after reading it as so "Date: June 17, 1997" with something similar to "System.out.println(date);".

So the problem I have is being able to iterate through each line properly. I have a while loop that will scan all the lines in the text file but only the last line is accessible once it's done. How do I code it so that I can access each line one at a time sequentially?

For those of you interested this is the [assignment.](http://cs.utsa.edu/~cs3443/laboratories/lab3.html)

Here is my code so far and sorry if I wasn't clear enough in explaining what I'm trying to do, I'm new to this.

```
public class Date {

private int month; // 1-12
private int monthNum; // number of month
private int day; // 1-31 varies by month
private int year; // any year
private String chkMonth, chkDay;
private String theMonth;
private int theYear,valid;

/**
 * days in each month with 0 at the index since there is no month "zero"
 */
private static final int[] daysPerMonth = { 0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31,
        31, 30, 31, 30, 31 };

/**
 * constructor: call checkMonth to confirm proper value for month; call
 * checkDay to confirm proper value for day
 * 
 * @param theMonth
 *            the month of the year
 * @param theDay
 *            the day of the month
 * @param theYear
 *            the year
 */

public Date() {
    Scanner in = null;
    try {
        in = new Scanner(new File("dates.txt"));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException exception) {
        System.err.println("failed to open dates.txt");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    while (in.hasNextLine()) {
        theMonth = in.next();
        chkMonth = theMonth.replaceAll("\\.", "");
        chkMonth = chkMonth.toLowerCase();
        chkDay = in.next();
        chkDay = chkDay.replaceAll("\\,", "");
        day = Integer.parseInt(chkDay);
        theYear = in.nextInt();
        // need more code for DateRange objects
        valid = 1;
        year = theYear; // could validate year
        if (checkMonth(chkMonth) == 0)
            valid = 0; // validate month

        if ((checkDay(day)) == 0)
            valid = 0; // validate day

        System.out.println(this);

    }

}



/**
 * utility method to confirm proper month value
 * 
 * @param theMonth
 * @return testMonth or throw an IllegalArgumentException
 */
private int checkMonth(String theMonth) {
    if (((theMonth.compareTo("jan")) == 0)
            || ((theMonth.compareTo("january")) == 0))
        monthNum = 1;
    else if (((theMonth.compareTo("feb")) == 0)
            || ((theMonth.compareTo("february")) == 0))
        monthNum = 2;
    else if (((theMonth.compareTo("mar")) == 0)
            || ((theMonth.compareTo("march")) == 0))
        monthNum = 3;
    else if (((theMonth.compareTo("apr")) == 0)
            || ((theMonth.compareTo("april")) == 0))
        monthNum = 4;
    else if (((theMonth.compareTo("may")) == 0))
        monthNum = 5;
    else if (((theMonth.compareTo("june")) == 0))
        monthNum = 6;
    else if (((theMonth.compareTo("july")) == 0))
        monthNum = 7;
    else if (((theMonth.compareTo("aug")) == 0)
            || ((theMonth.compareTo("august")) == 0))
        monthNum = 8;
    else if (((theMonth.compareTo("sept")) == 0)
            || ((theMonth.compareTo("september")) == 0))
        monthNum = 9;
    else if (((theMonth.compareTo("oct")) == 0)
            || ((theMonth.compareTo("october")) == 0))
        monthNum = 10;
    else if (((theMonth.compareTo("nov")) == 0)
            || ((theMonth.compareTo("november")) == 0))
        monthNum = 11;
    else if (((theMonth.compareTo("dec")) == 0)
            || ((theMonth.compareTo("december")) == 0))
        monthNum = 12;

    if (monthNum > 0 && monthNum <= 12) // validate month
        return monthNum;
    else
        return monthNum = 0;
    /*
     * else // month is invalid throw new
     * IllegalArgumentException("month must be 1-12");
     */
}

/**
 * utility method to confirm proper day value based on month and year
 * 
 * @param testDay
 * @return testDay or throw an IllegalArgumentException
 */
private int checkDay(int testDay) {
    // check if day in range for month
    if (testDay > 0 && testDay <= daysPerMonth[monthNum])
        return testDay;

    // check for leap year
    if (monthNum == 2 && testDay == 29
            && (year % 400 == 0 || (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0)))
        return testDay;

    // System.out.println("Invalid Date");

    return 0;

}

/**
 * return a String of the form month/day/year
 * 
 * @return a String of the form month/day/year
 */
public String toString() {
    if (valid == 1) {
        String ret = "Date: ";
        ret += theMonth + " ";
        ret += day + ", ";
        ret += year;
        return ret;
    } else
        return "Date Invalid";

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code for processing the file should *not* be in the Date class, but in the **Lab3** class. Moreover, your Date constructor should have parameters, like so:

```
public Date(theMonth, theDay, theYear) {
    this.year = theYear;
    this.month = theMonth;
    this.day = theDay;
}
```

Then in your Lab3 class, you can create a new Date object by doing the following:

```
Date nextDate = new Date(in.next(), in.next(), in.nextInt());
```

Of course, you'd need to do a bit more error-checking than that.

It would also help to store all the Date objects you've created somewhere, such as in an ArrayList.

Comment: Thanks, that at least gives me an idea on how to structure it. I have tried reading it from my Lab03 class. However I get lost with the idea of how to store date objects. I can't seem to find how to make ArrayList objects. I've tried Date date[i] = new Date(parameters) but haven't found a proper way of creating an ArrayList of dates all while reading the parameters in from Scanner.

Comment: You should create and initialize the ArrayList before reading the file. `ArrayList<Date> myDates = new ArrayList<Date>();` for example. It will initially be empty, but for every Date object that you read in, you can do `myDates.add(nextDate);`

Comment: I also should say, the reason for an ArrayList vs. an array is that in this case, you don't really know how many dates are in the file, right? So if you're using an array, how big do you make it? I hope that clarifies it a bit more.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into ArrayList, makes much more sense hearing it that way. If I had enough reputation I'd up vote it since I think comments just thanking a person aren't allowed. Still new to posting etiquette as well.